# Spark cluster only using master

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark 1.1.0 cluster with three machines of differing power. When I run the start-all.sh script and check the UI I have all slaves and the master listed. Each worker is listed (they have differing number of cores) with the number of cores listed correctly but the notice that zero are used.

```
cores
4 (0 Used)
2 (0 Used)
8 (8 Used)
```

Ssh is set up and working, hadoop seems fine too. The 8 core machine is the master so any submitted job runs only there. I see it being executed in the web UI but the other workers are never given work.

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening here is that the Total_Input_File_Size could be less than MAX_SPLIT_SIZE. So, there will be only one mapper running which will be executing only on the master.

The number of mappers generated are Total_Input_File_Size/MAX_SPLIT_SIZE. So, if you have given a small file, try to give a large input file or lower the value of max_split_size.

Let me know if the problem is anything else.

Comment: Odd you mention that. This is an unusual job in that it has many input files, all part-xxxxx file in several directories. The input is a comma delimited list. Each part file is fairly small. The total data is ~ 150m and the job takes forever to complete where single large files complete much quicker. Should I pass in just the dirs or cat all the files?

Comment: I think there is something else going on since the master UI is where it reports 0 used even before the job is launched

Comment: Then it increases more chance that only one mapper is being used. Try split-size=150/4 m

Comment: I see no mention of max_split_size in the Spark docs. Not using hadoop mapred.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `--deploy-mode cluster` in your `spark-submit` command?

if you empty this option, the application will not travel to other workers.

Comment: not using spark-submit running a standalone app that creates a context and throws closures at it. Is there a runtime SparkConf setting I need to make?

Comment: hi, @pferrel, take a look at this _The spark-submit script in Spark’s bin directory is used to launch applications on a cluster. It can use all of Spark’s supported cluster managers through a uniform interface so you don’t have to configure your application specially for each one._